# Calculate speed from network location

Tags: android, android-location

Iam trying to calculate speed ( using distance/time).  I know there getSpeed method on Location, but I tried it while driving and GPS on and it was not accurate at all My calculations were closer to reality.

Anyways, my question is , is there any way I can get speed using network location within a certain error range? Right now , it is throwing values like 100 km/hr and 5 km/hr for every location  I get in the network and I am not if there is reliable way. I currently just make sure that whatever location I get from network is newer than the previous network location

Thank you

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean section Examples - In Physics and Weighted harmonic mean.

Comment: Thank you, but why would it be suitable (as opposed to avg value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a list of locations, my suggestion is that, filter your location data received from network.

1. Speed is one of the factor you can use to filter.
2. You may try other ways to filter, like points in the wrong direction or far away from your path.
3. Increase the frequency of your location collection.
4. "accuracy" value from the network location data. But be careful with this. Big value doesn't always mean bad location, and small value doesn't always mean good location.  After filtered, you may calculate your speed again.